# Javascript: Grab value before and after specific value in array

Tags: javascript, arrays, for-loop, key

I'm trying to grab the value before and after a specific array value.

Like this

```
var arr = ["model", "color", "handle", "front", "extras"];
var category = "color";

for(i in array) {
  if(array[i] == category {
  //grab in this case model and handle
  }
}
```

I have tried a number of things such as: adding keys to the array, forcing the array to an object, but nothing helps..

Thanks in advance

Comment: Use `indexOf` to find the element. [`for..in` shouldn't be used on arrays](http://stackoverflow.com/q/500504/5743988).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `indexOf` to get the index of the category. Then knowing the index you can do -1 or +1 to get the values before and after.

If there is no value after or before, say in this example the category was "extras", then it will return undefined. You'll probably need to check if the value is undefined before you use it.

```
var arr = ["model", "color", "handle", "front", "extras"];
var category = "color";

var i = arr.indexOf(category);

var val1 = arr[i-1];
var val2 = arr[i+1];
```

Comment: Don't forget to test if it's not the first or last index to avoid error.

Comment: @Kolby Thank you for your answer, this solution works great!

Answer (score 0):

You might do as follows;

```js
var arr = ["model", "color", "handle", "front", "extras"],
   doit = (arr,str) => { fi = arr.indexOf(str);
                         return [arr[fi-1],str,arr[fi+1]];
                       };

console.log(doit(arr,"model"));
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, also a great solution ;)